# Sam Deploy Error: Require value for either DefinitionBody or DefinitionUri

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-cloudformation, aws-api-gateway, aws-sam

Sam Deploy erroring out with "Require value for either DefinitionBody or DefinitionUri".

Below is full sam template used:

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'
Transform: AWS::Serverless-2016-10-31
Description: >
  try

  Sample SAM Template for try

# More info about Globals: https://github.com/awslabs/serverless-application-model/blob/master/docs/globals.rst
Globals:
  Function:
    Timeout: 3
    Tracing: Active
  Api:
    TracingEnabled: true

Resources:
  ApiGatewayApi:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Api
    Properties:
      StageName: Prod
  CreateFunction:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function # More info about Function Resource: https://github.com/awslabs/serverless-application-model/blob/master/versions/2016-10-31.md#awsserverlessfunction
    Properties:
      CodeUri: ./create
      Handler: app.lambdaHandler
      Runtime: nodejs18.x
      Architectures:
      - x86_64
      Events:
        CreateItem:
          Type: Api # More info about API Event Source: https://github.com/awslabs/serverless-application-model/blob/master/versions/2016-10-31.md#api
          Properties:
            RestApiId: !Ref ApiGatewayApi
            Path: /create
            Method: post
      Environment:
        Variables:
          DBTable: !Ref myDynamoDBTable
      Policies:
        - DynamoDBWritePolicy:
            TableName: !Ref myDynamoDBTable
  GetFunction:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function 
    Properties:
      CodeUri: ./get
      Handler: app.lambdaHandler
      Runtime: nodejs18.x
      Architectures:
      - x86_64
      Events:
        CreateItem:
          Type: Api
          Properties:
            RestApiId: !Ref ApiGatewayApi
            Path: get
            Method: get
  GetAllFunction:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
    Properties:
      CodeUri: ./getAll
      Handler: app.lambdaHandler
      Runtime: nodejs18.x
      Architectures:
      - x86_64
      Events:
        CreateItem:
          Type: Api 
          Properties:
            RestApiId: !Ref ApiGatewayApi
            Path: /getAll
            Method: get
  UpdateFunction:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
    Properties:
      CodeUri: ./update
      Handler: app.lambdaHandler
      Runtime: nodejs18.x
      Architectures:
      - x86_64
      Events:
        CreateItem:
          Type: Api
          Properties:
            RestApiId: !Ref ApiGatewayApi
            Path: /update
            Method: put
      Environment:
        Variables:
          DBTable: !Ref myDynamoDBTable
      Policies:
        - DynamoDBWritePolicy:
            TableName: !Ref myDynamoDBTable
  DeleteFunction:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
    Properties:
      CodeUri: ./delete
      Handler: app.lambdaHandler
      Runtime: nodejs18.x
      Architectures:
      - x86_64
      Events:
        CreateItem:
          Type: Api
          Properties:
            RestApiId: !Ref ApiGatewayApi
            Path: /delete
            Method: delete
  myDynamoDBTable: 
    Type: AWS::DynamoDB::Table
    Properties: 
      AttributeDefinitions: 
        - 
          AttributeName: "user_id"
          AttributeType: "S"
        -
          AttributeName: "timestamp"
          AttributeType: "S"
      KeySchema: 
        - 
          AttributeName: "user_id"
          KeyType: "HASH"
        -
          AttributeName: "timestamp"
          KeyType: "RANGE"
      ProvisionedThroughput: 
        ReadCapacityUnits: "5"
        WriteCapacityUnits: "5"
      TableName: "dynamoDBTable"

  ApplicationResourceGroup:
    Type: AWS::ResourceGroups::Group
    Properties:
      Name:
        Fn::Join:
        - ''
        - - ApplicationInsights-SAM-
          - Ref: AWS::StackName
      ResourceQuery:
        Type: CLOUDFORMATION_STACK_1_0
  ApplicationInsightsMonitoring:
    Type: AWS::ApplicationInsights::Application
    Properties:
      ResourceGroupName:
        Fn::Join:
        - ''
        - - ApplicationInsights-SAM-
          - Ref: AWS::StackName
      AutoConfigurationEnabled: 'true'
    DependsOn: ApplicationResourceGroup
Outputs:
  # ServerlessRestApi is an implicit API created out of Events key under Serverless::Function
  # Find out more about other implicit resources you can reference within SAM
  # https://github.com/awslabs/serverless-application-model/blob/master/docs/internals/generated_resources.rst#api
  Api:
    Description: API Gateway endpoint URL for Prod stage for Create function
    Value: !Sub "https://${ApiGatewayApi}.execute-api.${AWS::Region}.amazonaws.com/Prod"
  CreateFunction:
    Description: Create Lambda Function ARN
    Value: !GetAtt CreateFunction.Arn
  CreateFunctionIamRole:
    Description: Implicit IAM Role created for Create function
    Value: !GetAtt CreateFunctionRole.Arn
  UpdateFunction:
    Description: Update Lambda Function ARN
    Value: !GetAtt UpdateFunction.Arn
  UpdateFunctionIamRole:
    Description: Implicit IAM Role created for Update function
    Value: !GetAtt UpdateFunctionRole.Arn
  GetFunctionIamRole:
    Description: Implicit IAM Role created for Get function
    Value: !GetAtt GetFunctionRole.Arn
  GetFunction:
    Description: Get Lambda Function ARN
    Value: !GetAtt GetFunction.Arn
  GetAllFunctionIamRole:
    Description: Implicit IAM Role created for GetAll function
    Value: !GetAtt GetAllFunctionRole.Arn
  GetAllFunction:
    Description: GetAll Lambda Function ARN
    Value: !GetAtt GetAllFunction.Arn
  DeleteFunctionIamRole:
    Description: Implicit IAM Role created for Delete function
    Value: !GetAtt DeleteFunctionRole.Arn
  DeleteFunction:
    Description: Delete Lambda Function ARN
    Value: !GetAtt DeleteFunction.Arn
  DynamoDB:
    Description: DynamoDB Table Name
    Value: !Ref myDynamoDBTable
```

Full error trackback:

```
Error: Require value for either DefinitionBody or DefinitionUri
Traceback:
  File "C:\Program Files\Amazon\AWSSAMCLI\runtime\lib\site-packages\click\core.py", line 1055, in main
    rv = self.invoke(ctx)
  File "C:\Program Files\Amazon\AWSSAMCLI\runtime\lib\site-packages\click\core.py", line 1657, in invoke
    return _process_result(sub_ctx.command.invoke(sub_ctx))
  File "C:\Program Files\Amazon\AWSSAMCLI\runtime\lib\site-packages\click\core.py", line 1404, in invoke
    return ctx.invoke(self.callback, **ctx.params)
  File "C:\Program Files\Amazon\AWSSAMCLI\runtime\lib\site-packages\click\core.py", line 760, in invoke
    return __callback(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Program Files\Amazon\AWSSAMCLI\runtime\lib\site-packages\samcli\lib\cli_validation\image_repository_validation.py", line 92, in wrapped
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Program Files\Amazon\AWSSAMCLI\runtime\lib\site-packages\click\decorators.py", line 84, in new_func
    return ctx.invoke(f, obj, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Program Files\Amazon\AWSSAMCLI\runtime\lib\site-packages\click\core.py", line 760, in invoke
    return __callback(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Program Files\Amazon\AWSSAMCLI\runtime\lib\site-packages\samcli\lib\telemetry\metric.py", line 183, in wrapped
    raise exception  # pylint: disable=raising-bad-type
  File "C:\Program Files\Amazon\AWSSAMCLI\runtime\lib\site-packages\samcli\lib\telemetry\metric.py", line 148, in wrapped
    return_value = func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Program Files\Amazon\AWSSAMCLI\runtime\lib\site-packages\samcli\lib\utils\version_checker.py", line 42, in wrapped
    actual_result = func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Program Files\Amazon\AWSSAMCLI\runtime\lib\site-packages\samcli\cli\main.py", line 92, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Program Files\Amazon\AWSSAMCLI\runtime\lib\site-packages\samcli\commands\_utils\cdk_support_decorators.py", line 39, in wrapped
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Program Files\Amazon\AWSSAMCLI\runtime\lib\site-packages\samcli\commands\_utils\command_exception_handler.py", line 93, in wrapper_command_exception_handler
    raise ex
  File "C:\Program Files\Amazon\AWSSAMCLI\runtime\lib\site-packages\samcli\commands\_utils\command_exception_handler.py", line 73, in wrapper_command_exception_handler
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Program Files\Amazon\AWSSAMCLI\runtime\lib\site-packages\samcli\commands\deploy\command.py", line 194, in cli
    do_cli(
  File "C:\Program Files\Amazon\AWSSAMCLI\runtime\lib\site-packages\samcli\commands\deploy\command.py", line 286, in do_cli
    guided_context.run()
  File "C:\Program Files\Amazon\AWSSAMCLI\runtime\lib\site-packages\samcli\commands\deploy\guided_context.py", line 558, in run
    self.guided_prompts(_parameter_override_keys)
  File "C:\Program Files\Amazon\AWSSAMCLI\runtime\lib\site-packages\samcli\commands\deploy\guided_context.py", line 161, in guided_prompts
    self.prompt_authorization(stacks)
  File "C:\Program Files\Amazon\AWSSAMCLI\runtime\lib\site-packages\samcli\commands\deploy\guided_context.py", line 205, in prompt_authorization
    auth_required_per_resource = auth_per_resource(stacks)
  File "C:\Program Files\Amazon\AWSSAMCLI\runtime\lib\site-packages\samcli\commands\deploy\auth_utils.py", line 39, in auth_per_resource
    _auth_resource_event(sam_function_provider, sam_function, _auth_per_resource)
  File "C:\Program Files\Amazon\AWSSAMCLI\runtime\lib\site-packages\samcli\commands\deploy\auth_utils.py", line 73, in _auth_resource_event
    elif _auth_id(
  File "C:\Program Files\Amazon\AWSSAMCLI\runtime\lib\site-packages\samcli\commands\deploy\auth_utils.py", line 107, in _auth_id
    _auth_definition_body_and_uri(
  File "C:\Program Files\Amazon\AWSSAMCLI\runtime\lib\site-packages\samcli\commands\deploy\auth_utils.py", line 133, in _auth_definition_body_and_uri
    reader = SwaggerReader(definition_body=definition_body, definition_uri=definition_uri)
  File "C:\Program Files\Amazon\AWSSAMCLI\runtime\lib\site-packages\samcli\commands\local\lib\swagger\reader.py", line 91, in __init__
    raise ValueError("Require value for either DefinitionBody or DefinitionUri")
```

I thought one issue could be codeUri of the lambda function resources but the path to the Handler seems correct. Another issue I suspect is not specifying a swagger.yaml for the openapi resource, but I have seen sam templates with one api gateway and multiple lambda resources elsewhere in similar format. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: It seems I forgot to sam build after updating the template file. Issue was resolved after doing another sam build -> sam deploy.

Answer (score 0):

Issue was I forgot to `sam build` again after updating the template files.
`.aws-sam/build directory` still had incorrect CodeUri for the lambda function resources within template.yaml. Resolved issue by using `sam build -> sam deploy` after template.yaml was updated.